# Specific example of recursion in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

```
polarbear([],H,[H]). 
polarbear([H|T],Y,[H|Z]):- polarbear(T,Y,Z).
```

This is the prolog code. When entering `?-polarbear([1,2], 6, P).` Get `P =[1,2,6].`

The thing is I just don't understand how it's working and I've been trying to work out how Prolog is doing what it's doing.

I have some experience with Prolog, but I don't understand this, so any guidance as to how it does what it does in order to help me understand Prolog would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

states that the first argument is a list with head H and tail T and the third argument is a list with head H and tail Z. So it forces (by using unification) the heads of the two lists to be the same. Recursively the two lists become identical except the fact that the third argument list has one more element in the end (element Y) and this is defined by the first clause. Note that second clause only works for lists with one or more elements. So as a base of the recursion when we examine the empty list then the third list due to first clause contains only one more element the element Y.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely helped. So it tries the first clause and fails, then it splits the list provided into head and tail, the 6 becomes Y and the final argument remains as an unknown variable. Then it runs Polarbear again, fails the first clause again, goes to the second clause again and then that's where I get confused how does it move the values around. Sorry I'm just trying to understand exactly what it does think I'm out of my depth but can't find a good resource.

Comment: First call (second clause): H = 1, T = [2], Y = 6. Second call: H = 2, T = [], Y = 6. Third call the first clause matches, so list = [6]. Then back to second call (H = 2), list = [2,6], first call (H = 1) list = [1,2,6].